# Elegant way of finding expressions

Tags: python, string

I have some troubles finding some **clear** and **readable** solution to my problem.
So I have some messages that all have the same format :

```py
message = "sender -> receiver : message_name [param1 : value1, ..., param_n : value_n] \
Loop : value Par : value Par_id : value"
```

The message is generated so it always has the same format, the only thing that changes from one message to another are the values of the **Par** **Par_id** and **Loop** (**always integers**), and the **number of parameters** (can be 0 : `[]` or multiple : `[Param1 : value1, Param2 : value2, Param3 : value3]`)

Obviously the message name, sender and receiver are not always the same but I guess that doesn't really matter because it doesn't impact that way the string is constructed.

For instance one message could be :

```py
'c -> i : C_I_status [eStatus : 1, eSceEnd : 4] Loop : 0 Par : 0 Par_id : -1'
```

I would like to **format** these messages in the following format :

```py
[sender, receiver, message_name, [ [param1, value1], ..., [param_n, value_n] ], loop_value, par_value, par_id_value]
```

With the example above I would have the output :

```py
['c', 'i', 'C_I_status', [ ['eStatus', '1'], ['eSceEnd', '4'] ], '0', '0', '-1']
```

So far I have tried to **split** and **strip** but I am getting all confused with so many list items and ways of cutting my string in order to have the correct format. Here is what I came with : (it gets messy when it comes to the parameters)

```py
  sender = line.split(' ', 6)[0]
  receiver = line.split(' ', 6)[2]
  message_name = line.split(' ', 6)[4]
  params = [i.split(':') for i in line.split(' ', 6)[5].strip('[]').split(',')]
  looped = line.split(' ', 6)[6].split(' ')[2]
  pared = line.split(' ', 6)[6].split(' ')[5]
  pared_id = line.split(' ', 6)[6].split(' ')[8]
  message_stack.append([sender, receiver, message_name, params, looped, pared])
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: A regex would be a handy tool in this case. But also string operations could be done way better

Comment: I am totally new to regex and never have used them before. What should be the reasoning behind regex ? What question should I be asking myself in order to format my string the way I want to ?

Comment: Also check sample input in the params part - `[param1 : value1, ..., param_n, value_n]` - what is the separator `:` or `,`

Comment: the separator for a parameter is the ','. Parameters should be considered in pair as each parameter has its own value, the we move on to a new parameter with the ','

Comment: edit your question to fix the discrepancy in the message tempalte

Comment: Also compare `Loop : value, Par : value, Par_id : value"` in the template vs `Loop : 0 Par : 0 Par_id : -1'` in the sample message. missing commas in the msg or wrong template?

Comment: there are no commas that separate the ```Loop : 0 Par : 0 Par_id : -1```, however in the formatting I only need to retrieve the values of Loop Par and Par_id

Comment: God sorry it was so confusing it took time for me to understand what you meant by template ! should be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use regex, but it is probably good to know if that is always the format (is the message code generated? are the spaces always the same? are `Loop`, `Par`, and `Par_id` always there? are the numbers always integers?). If so, the regex can be quite simple (not sure about the readability):

```py
import re

s = 'c -> i : C_I_status [eStatus : 1, eSceEnd : 4] Loop : 0 Par : 0 Par_id : -1'

# Extract all the required information to a list
match = re.findall('(\w+) -> (\w+) : (\w+) (\[.*\]) \w+ : (-*\d+) \w+ : (-*\d+) \w+ : (-*\d+)', s)
if match:  # If the message is well formated, it should have 1 element inside
    parts = list(match[0])
    # Deal with the information between `[]`
    parts[3] = [x.split(' : ') for x in re.findall('\w+ : -*\d+',     parts[3])]
    # ['c', 'i', 'C_I_status', [['eStatus', '1'], ['eSceEnd', '4']], '0', '0', '-1']
```

Some of the key things you need to know:

- `\w+` matches any alpha characters (the plus means 1 or more times)
- `-*\d+` matches any digits (the `-*` is an optional negative sign)
- `\[.*\]` is matching anything (.*) between `[]`
- The `()`  are capture groups (i.e. only things between `()` are returned)

You can also adapt that regex for variable spaces, decimal numbers, etc. but it gets a bit more complex.

Comment: The message is generated so it always has the same format, the only thing that changes from one message to another are the values of the Par Par_id and Loop (always integers), and the number of parameters (can be 0 : [] or multiple : [Param1 : value1, Param2 : value2, Param3 : value3]

Comment: @MaximeBouhadana this is important info and should be in the question itself

Comment: Thank you for the solution it does work ! I will definitely dig on this Re module that I never used ! Thanks for the clarification on the syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a solution that combines both regular expressions and `split()` string functions to achieve the desired output:

```
import re
s = 'c -> i : C_I_status [eStatus : 1] Loop : 0 Par : 0 Par_id : -1'

s = s.split(":")
s = s[0].split("->") + s[1:]
s[4:6] = [re.sub("[^0-9]", "", i) for i in s[4:6]]
s[2:4] = [s[2].split("[")[0], [[s[2].split("[")[1], s[3].split("]")[0]]]]
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
['c ', ' i ', ' C_I_status ', [['eStatus ', ' 1']], '0', '0', ' -1']
```

Comment: i think its not good for more param:value